# using a variable inside json

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I have a json object "shopping_cart", and inside it another object called "items".

I want to update the json object once the user adds some new items on the cart, so
I add a new item on "items" object. Now the thing is that the new item that will be
added to "items" object needs to have some sort of identifier, so whenever the user
adds a new item it'll be:

```
$.extend(shopping_cart.items,{ "item_2":...
$.extend(shopping_cart.items,{ "item_3":...
```

etc.

I try replacing the number below (1) with a variable

```
$.extend(shopping_cart.items,{ "item_1": {"item_name":"fafafa", "qty":"", "price":"", "discount":"", "subtotal":""}});
```

Something like:
var new_num = 5;

```
$.extend(shopping_cart.items,{ "item_"+new_num: {"item_name":"fafafa", "qty":"", "price":"", "discount":"", "subtotal":""}});
```

So that it translates to:

```
 $.extend(shopping_cart.items,{ item_5
```

But no luck, no matter what way I try the variable is parsed as a string at all cases.

So is there any way to create an object dynamically by using variables? I'll also need
this to update item_name, qty, price etc with dynamic variables.

Thank you alot.

Comment: We actually don't use item_1, item_2, etc. we use an array for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're only adding a single item, there's no need to use jQuery's `extend`. Just set the attribute:

```
shopping_cart.items["item_"+new_num] = {"item_name":"fafafa", "qty":"", "price":"", "discount":"", "subtotal":""};
```

Within `[...]`, you are allowed to do string manipulation. Within `{...:...}`, you are not.

Comment: Im not adding a single item. That was just to describe the situation.

Comment: @bornie You can still do it this way; just use one line for each item. It will be faster than jQuery's `extend` too (`extend` is intended for situations where there could already be an item with the same name, and you'd like to augment it rather than replace it). If you *really* want to use extend, create a new object by this method then pass that to extend.